# ModuleNotFound in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

i am getting this error in cmd prompt : No module named 'urllib.request'
i have installed pip and requests packages still i am getting this

```py
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
fhand = urllib.request.open('https://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

Comment: if you need to import all those, you need to use ```from urllib import request, parse, error```.  That said,    ```urllib.request``` doesn't have the open() method.  (afaik)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code below:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen(url)
```

for your use case

```
from urllib import request, parse, error
fhand =request.urlopen('https://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

I've seen Python 3 has depreciated urllib itself and replaced it with a number of libraries including urllib.request,if above doesn't work, I have found a hack for

Try using `urllib2`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

This line should work to replace urlopen:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
```

Tested in Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent libraries:

1. The standard library package `urllib` provides `urllib.request.urlopen()` (not `open`)

As this is part of the Python, nothing needs to be installed with `pip`.

But your code should not fail with import error, the examples for Python 3.7 import the module in the same way: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html#examples

Please update your question and provide more information about the error.

2. The popular and superior package `requests` has `requests.get()`:

You wrote, that you have installed this package with `pip`. This was not necessary.